# FieldValue.arrayRemove() to remove an object from array of objects based on property value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with the following structure:

```
{
    "email" : "a@gmail.com",
    "value" : 100,
    "children" : [
                  {
                    "email" : "b@gmail.com",
                    "value" : 100
                  },
                  {
                    "email" : "b@gmail.com",
                    "value" : 200
                  }
                 ]
}
```

I want to remove all elements with the email `b@gmail.com` from the `children` array. I am able to remove one item if I pass the whole object to be removed like this:

`FieldValue.arrayRemove(childObject)`

But I want both the objects with the email `b@gmail.com` to be removed. Is there anyway to achieve this using `FieldValue.arrayRemove()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `arrayRemove` operation removes the exact item that you specify from the array. There is no way to pass a partial object and remove all array items that match the partial information. You will have to pass in each complete item that you want to remove.

If you don't know what those items are yet, you will typically have to first read the document, loop over the items in the array to remove them, and write the modified array back to the document.

Comment: Is this feature likely to be supported in the future?

Comment: Nobody is actively working on adding partial array operations at the moment. If you'd like to cast your vote for them to be added, you can [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But for now, you will have to query-then-remove.

Answer (score 2):

As an update, it is still the case that you must match the object exactly to remove it from an array.  Additionally, of course, in the example above, he is querying for a value, which requires a query to see what matches.

However, depending on the logic: if you use a Map instead...for instance in the case above, adjusted:

```
"children" : 
    "b@gmail.com_100":
                      {
                        "email" : "b@gmail.com",
                        "value" : 100
                      },
    "b@gmail.com_200":
                      {
                        "email" : "b@gmail.com",
                        "value" : 200
                      }
```

You can simply use:

```
'children.b@gmail.com_200': FieldValue.delete(),
```

As of late, I've gravitated away from Lists to Maps for this reason.

Comment: Hello, I want to change this 'children.b@gmail.com_200' with  'children.${mail}', but not sure for the right syntax, can you help me with that?

Comment: String var = 'b@gmail.com_200'; 'children.$var' should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not working :/