# How to remove an element from an array in multiple documents in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of users. Each user has an array named `favoriteNames`.

```
root <- [Firestore]
 users <- [Collection]
   uid <- [Document]
    favoriteNames: ["Ana", "Jane", "Dave"] <- [Array]
   uid<- [Document]
    favoriteNames: ["Ana", "Merry", "John"] <- [Array]
```

I want to remove "Ana" from all documents. This is what I tried:

```
usersRef.whereArrayContains("favoriteNames", FieldValue.arrayRemove("Ana").get()
```

But it doesn't work. How can I remove "Ana" from all arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do a SQL-like "update where" type query with Firestore.  If you have multiple documents to update, you will have to update each one individually.  You can use a transaction or batch write to do all the updates atomically, if needed.

Minimally, what you will have to do here is:

1. Query for all the documents to update.  This will involve doing an [array-contains query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) for all "Ana".

   ```
   usersRef.whereArrayContains("favoriteNames", "Ana")
   ```
2. Iterate the query results.
3. For each matching [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), get its DocumentReference and use `update()` with `FieldValue.arrayRemove("Ana")`

   ```
   snapshot.reference.update("favoriteNames", FieldValue.arrayRemove("Ana"))
   ```

Comment: Thank you Doug for reopening the question. I think the one who closed it didn't really understand what I was actually asking :( I see now, there are two steps required to perform the update in all documents. This is what I was looking for. Saved my day!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not getting your question wrong you want from one array remove a specific item, in this case "Ana".
I've created a sample doing so, let me know if is what you are looking for.

```
fun main() {
  val a = arrayListOf("Joan", "Skizo", "Ana")
  val b = a.minus("Ana")
  print(b)
}
```

What is printing is

> [Joan, Skizo]

To do so, you can use [`minus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html)

> Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection without the first occurrence of the given element.

Regarding this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694940/fieldvalue-arrayremove-to-remove-an-object-from-array-of-objects-based-on-prop) you'd have to read, write what you want and then remove them from the list and then write it back.

Also this might help you with the `update` method I'd say :
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#arrayRemove-examples

This question might help you also [remove array elements in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983589/4385913)

Comment: Thanks but those arrays are actually in Firestore. Please check the edit.

Comment: According to the first answer example, I am passing the entire object to `arrayRemove` function. There's nothing missing in this object ("Ana"). The second answer is only updating a single document, I need to update all documents in a collection. `whereArrayContains` is a Query, returns multiple documents.

Comment: @LisDya you need to perform this operation programmatically, as is mentioned in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484348/11529321

Comment: Exactly you need to add an `update` block and then remove the "Ana" thingy